# Decimal value in ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a little problem with a decimal value inside the ASP.NET MVC application I'm writing. I have a NPoco binding to a database table and a `Price` entry that is defined as decimal(9,2). Here is the model entry that I use:

```
[Display(Name = "Price")]
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0,##}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Next I have a knockout js model that binds all the parameters and works fine. Every other field is taken and bound correctly. For what concern the price I have this piece of html code:

```
<input type="text" required data-bind="value: Price" class="form-control input-sm" id="priceID"/>
```

Now if I insert a value with the comma everything works fine and the value is inserted inside the db correctly (e.g. 15,20) but if I use the dot a 0.00 value is inserted inside the database. The funny thing is when I reload the object for edit it the value of price is set and write with the dot inside the html page.

So my question: is there is a method to accept both format (means with the dot and the comma)?

Comment: And now I want to use a price of 10,000. Did I mean ten or ten thousand?

Comment: I would suggest you to separate the UI Culture from your backend culture in order to avoid this problem. Please take a look on this blog: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/mar/27/auto-selecting-cultures-for-localization-in-aspnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, although you can force one locale with `<html lang="en-US" >` and/or handle input accordingly.

Each users experience will differ based on their computers regional settings and it may not be wise to force the seperator to be a comma, or vice-versa. But you can, replacing or disabling input of said chars.

Probably the most elegant way is to handle everything on the server side, converting between locales.